# QGIS layer stretched

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, wgs84

I try to work out a way to assemble the layers I have got in my QGIS project so that no layer appears to be stretched.

**original coordinate systems:**

vector layer: WGS 84 UTM Zone 34N

raster layer: WGS 1984

In the first case the raster layer appears stretched.

**coordinate systems in picture one:**

vektor layer: WGS 84 UTM Zone 34N

raster layer: WGS 1984

coordinate reference system: WGS 84 UTM Zone 34N

[image]

I can **change the coordinate reference system to WGS 1984**. What happens is that the raster layer looks fine but the vector layer is stretched.

[image]

This does make sense as I have different coordinate systems and QGIS tries to somehow add them together. The problem is that once I try to project any of the layers coordinate systems to the same coordinate systems as the other they appear at very different places.

**Is there any possibility to add all layers together without one being stretched?**

**It is also quite important for me to know if there are solutions to this in general or if there is nothing you can do about it sometimes.**

Comment: No there is nothing you can do about it, both layers have different coordinate systems and will appear slightly distorted against the other no matter what CRS you choose.. the good news is that it's a reliable distortion and every other layer you add afterwards will line up with your current layers within their own accuracy.

Comment: Note that reprojecting requires `Save As` for vector layers and `Raster -> Projections -> Warp` for rasters using a new filename. The **project** CRS can be different from the layer CRS. Don't use `Set Layer CRS`, it would spoil your data unless you know what you are doing. If you are in doubt, add a basemap from the QuickMapServices plugin to see which layer is at the right spot.